# Using JOLT Transformation Need to remove the sqaure brakets of an object

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying remove a field from array of JSON using JOLT Transformation. below is the input JSON and expected output JSON.

can you suggest the JOLT transformation for the mentioned scenario

**Input:**

```json
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "totalCount": 1,
    "SCount": 1,
    "FCount": 0,
    "FSequences": [],
    "token": [
      328358
    ]
  },
  "id": "ce27g26hvamob9lbd0eg"
}
```

**Jolt I'm using:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": "&"
      },
      "status|id": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected output:**

```json
{
  "totalCount" : 1,
  "SCount" : 1,
  "FCount" : 0,
  "FSequences" : "",
  "token" : "328358",
  "status" : 200,
  "id" : "ce27g26hvamob9lbd0eg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consecutively apply **shift** and **modify** specs such that

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": "&",
        "token": {
          "*": "&1" // replicates the tag "token" by grabbing after going up tree one level
        }
      },
      "code": "status", // renaming the attribute
      "id": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*u*n*": ["=toInteger", ""], // conversion only doesn't apply for "FSequences" among *u*n* tagged attributes
      "*o*n": "=toString" // only applied for "token" attribute
    }
  }
]
```